# How to fetch all items from a Content Collection

Tags: content-hub

Using Content Hub (CH) v4.2

I have created a `Content Collection` called "McDonalds Content Collection" which has an item of Content Type `Advertisement`.

[image]

Now, I would like to fetch all the data/items from the respective collections, For e.g., I want to get all the `Advertisements` and their data (Title, Image, Description) from "McDonalds Content Collection".

Or just all items in that collection with their details.

Here is my API query:

> https://{{hostname}}/api/entities/query?query=Int('id')==93451

93451 is the ID of my Collection item/folder.

This query returns information about the collection and not the items inside it. What should be the query to get only the data inside the collection.

**Response**

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 93451,
            "identifier": "LtgrELltiUyy8kRysWqNmA",
            "cultures": [
                "en-US"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "ContentCollectionName": "McDonalds Content Collection",
                "ContentCollectionDescription": null,
                "PreventPublish": null,
                "PublishStatus": {
                    "identifier": "Published",
                    "labels": {
                        "en-US": "Published"
                    }
                },
                "PublishStatusDetails": null
            },
            "relations": {
                "RoleProxyToContentCollection": {
                    "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/93451/relations/RoleProxyToContentCollection"
                },
                "ContentCollectionToMasterAsset": {
                    "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/93451/relations/ContentCollectionToMasterAsset"
                },
                "ContentRepositoryToContentCollection": {
                    "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/93451/relations/ContentRepositoryToContentCollection"
                },
                "StatusToContentCollection": {
                    "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/93451/relations/StatusToContentCollection"
                },
                "MContentCollectionToAvailableRoute": {
                    "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/93451/relations/MContentCollectionToAvailableRoute"
                },
                "MContentCollectionToActiveState": {
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/29917"
                        }
                    ],
                    "inherits_security": true,
                    "self": {
                        "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/93451/relations/MContentCollectionToActiveState"
                    }
                },
                "ContentCollectionToContent": {
                    "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/93451/relations/ContentCollectionToContent"
                },
                "MContentCollectionToStateMachine": {
                    "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/93451/relations/MContentCollectionToStateMachine"
                }
            },
            "created_by": {
                "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/92202",
                "title": "The user who created the entity"
            },
            "created_on": "2023-03-13T07:12:09.5920623Z",
            "modified_by": {
                "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/92202",
                "title": "The user who last modified the entity"
            },
            "modified_on": "2023-03-13T07:13:04.818515Z",
            "entitydefinition": {
                "href": "https://example.com/api/entitydefinitions/M.ContentCollection",
                "title": "The entity definition for this entity"
            },
            "copy": {
                "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/93451/copy",
                "title": "Copy this entity"
            },
            "permissions": {
                "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/93451/permissions",
                "title": "The permissions on this entity"
            },
            "lifecycle": {
                "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/93451/lifecycle",
                "title": "The lifecycle action for this entity."
            },
            "saved_selections": {
                "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/93451/savedselections",
                "title": "The saved selections this entity belongs to"
            },
            "roles": {
                "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/93451/roles",
                "title": "Roles for this entity"
            },
            "annotations": {
                "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/93451/annotations",
                "title": "Annotations for this entity"
            },
            "is_root_taxonomy_item": true,
            "is_path_root": false,
            "inherits_security": true,
            "is_system_owned": false,
            "version": 5,
            "self": {
                "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/93451"
            },
            "renditions": {}
        }
    ],
    "total_items": 1,
    "returned_items": 1,
    "self": {
        "href": "https://example.com/api/entities/query?query=Int(%27id%27)%3D%3D93451",
        "title": "This collection"
    }
}
```

Comment: https://{{hostname}}/api/entities/query?query=And(Equals(ContentTypeName,'Advertisements'),Equals(ContentCollectionName,'McDonalds Content Collection'))&take=1000 does it work for you?

Comment: @VadimBirkos Got this error `Parsing failure: unexpected 'd'; expected c (Line 1, Column 3); recently consumed: An`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have raised a support ticket with Sitecore and the 2nd approach they have suggested, worked for me.

**Approach 1:**
If you already know the ID of the collection, you can directly use

```
/api/entities/{id}/relations/ContentCollectionToContent
```

That output does not contain the items, this is because a `ContentCollection` can contain a lot of Content and the API returns a list of Content that are in the Collection. To get the information, you will need to navigate to the `href` and it will have the full data of a singular Content.

[image]

If you do not know the ID and require search, then:

`/api/entities/query?query=(Definition.Name == "M.ContentCollection" AND String('ContentCollectionName')=='McDonalds Content Collection')`

When you retrieve this result, you can get the ID then run the query

`api/entities/{id}/relations/ContentCollectionToContent`

**Approach 2:**
You can also do a reverse query on `M.Content` to find all `M.Content` in a specific `ContentCollection`. This also requires you to know the ID of the `ContentCollection`.
For example:

`/api/entities/query?query=(Definition.Name == "M.Content" AND Parent('ContentCollectionToContent').id=={id})`

In order to get only "Blogs" or "Advertisements", you could use the same query but append the condition

`AND Parent('ContentTypeToContent').id=={id}`

where ID is equal to the ID of the Content Type. 9786 for Blog and 9792 for Advertisement.

The related documentation is in https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/developers/42/cloud-dev/rest-api--query.html

All queries start with

`http://<hostname>/api/entities/query/`

Then you can append the query depending on what you need such as [Properties](https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/developers/42/cloud-dev/rest-api--generic-properties.html), [Specific system properties](https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/developers/42/cloud-dev/rest-api--specific-properties.html) and [other parameters](https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/developers/42/cloud-dev/rest-api--parameters.html) such as Relations, Operators and furthermore.

The query provided

`/api/entities/query?query=(Definition.Name == "M.Content" AND Parent('ContentCollectionToContent').id=={id})`

is used to search for all entities with `M.Content` as definition AND we are searching all entities that have the relation `ContentCollectionToContent == id`

Further, I had also requested more info about `Selection` API's documentation for which Sitecore has responded

> Regarding the api/selection that you have mentioned, we are sorry to
> inform you that the docs are outdated and this is not supported
> anymore. We have raised a request to the team to change the
> documentation.
>
> Regarding the documentation, this was missed when the functionality of
> the product was changed. We will provide feedback to the documentation
> team regarding this.